# How to get ISO CountryCode , Country Code programmatically in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

Is there any way to retreive the ISO Country Code/Country programmatically in Blackberry 5.0/6/0 devices

Comment: What do you mean?  Get the country code of the country the device is currently located in?  Or get the country code of a country by passing in its full string name?

Comment: Yes the country code of the device which is currently  located in and other thing will be useful in knowing

Comment: @Rakesh You mean the CC of the language set in the device, or the code of the country the device is actually located?

Comment: Getting Both will useful ,I am expecting both things also

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the country from the mobile network (if a SIM card is present). This is called [Mobile Country Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code). It is a number that you can then map to a string. In the API you have [`GPRSInfo.getHomeMCC`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/GPRSInfo.html#getHomeMCC%28%29). You can also call [`RadioInfo.getMCC`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioInfo.html#getMCC%28int%29) and even [`RadioInfo.getNetworkCountryCode`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioInfo.html#getNetworkCountryCode%28int%29), that will already return the text if the carrier supports it.

And to get the ISO code of the device language, you can call [`Locale.getDefaultForSystem().getCountry()`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/i18n/Locale.html#getCountry%28%29).